# What will happen when seconds since epoch > LONG_MAX?

Tags: c, time, epoch, time-t

For homework, I am writing a program that deals with a lot of `time_t` objects. I thought about checking them for overflow, but then it occurred to me that if they overflowed we would all be in a might bit of trouble.

Is there a plan for this? What will happen when the time since epoch exceeds storage?

Comment: I doubt there are any mainstream CRT implementations left that haven't made time_t a 64-bit type.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: @Hans: Wrong. `time_t` is 32-bit (`long`) on all existing 32-bit machines I know of, including in particular Linux/glibc. In any case, I think it's realistic to expect all 32-bit machines will be decommissioned by 2038...

Comment: @R.: Hopefully us greybeard C programmers will be able to command outrageously high hourly rates fixing the problem in about 2036 ;)

Comment: @caf unfortunately we won't be able to do that anymore because [64-bit `time_t` support was added to Linux 5.1 and glibc 2.32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14361651/995714)

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE some embedded systems that starts their life from now may still spend their lifetime in the next few decades. And 32-bit embedded systems will always live just like how 8-bit microcontrollers still exist nowadays, because many applications don't need such a huge performant processor

Comment: @phuclv: Yes, my prediction 8 years ago was rather inaccurate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LONG_MAX` on a 64-bit machine is `2^63 - 1`.  Try this: go to http://google.com and enter `2^63 seconds in years`.  Look at the answer and decide whether you really need to worry about it.

Comment: like like like. Yeah that's the funny thing about big number. I even thought, "oh maybe its just such a big number that we don't have to worry about it... nah 2^63 seconds is probably not THAT many years." I am satisfied with this answer.

Comment: I like the Wikipedia article on the issue. Using a signed 64-bit value introduces a new wraparound date at 15:30:08 on Sunday, 4 December 292,277,026,596. Will not be a problem for me at least.

Comment: Kind of makes me sad to think I may not be around to see this happen...in nearly 300 billion years from now. So puny.

Comment: @Brenden Not with that attitude you won't. ;^)

Comment: @r_ahlskog Oh dip! This will probably interfere with the planning of my birthday on December 7th, 292,277,026,596. Gotta make a note of that.